# How to Update Handle Current Album Image with XamarinMediaManager?

Tags: xamarin.forms, media-manager

How to Update Handle Current Album Image?

lib: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

```
var webImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/4/7/b/8/600_455178360.jpeg")) };

        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Title = "Changed Title";
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Artist= "Changed Artist";
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImage = webImage;
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImageUri = "https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/4/7/b/8/600_455178360.jpeg";
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImage = webImage;
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImageUri = "https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/4/7/b/8/600_455178360.jpeg";
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Image = webImage;
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.ImageUri = "https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/4/7/b/8/600_455178360.jpeg";

        CrossMediaManager.Current.Notification.UpdateNotification();

        Console.WriteLine("Changed");
```

There is no image in Android:
http://prntscr.com/qvlln8

Plugin.MediaManager: 0.9.6